# MongoDB Python list_database_names() Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I Am A Starter In Learning Mongo DB Atlas. I Am Facing A Error In This Code. While i print(only db) it returns a collection but the `client.list_database_names()` doesn't work it gives me the following error given down below.

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Belgin:***@cluster.0g9bt.mongodb.net/<dbname>? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.User_Details
db_list = client.list_database_names()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    db_list = client.list_database_names()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1915, in list_database_names
    for doc in self.list_databases(session, nameOnly=True)]
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1896, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 755, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1460, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1278, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 241, in select_server
    return random.choice(self.select_servers(selector,
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 199, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 215, in _select_servers_loop

raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5f6c28d15aa46e42105998eb, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster-shard-00-00.0g9bt.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster-shard-00-01.0g9bt.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>, <ServerDescription ('cluster-shard-00-02.0g9bt.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('connection closed')>]>
```

Comment: @deadshot ok let me try it

Comment: @deadshot Nope, it's not working. Decipated

Comment: try creating new database

Comment: Ok I Will give it a try

Comment: @deadshot still same error

Comment: Try the non-SRV connection string ("legacy driver").

Comment: @D.SM Can You Explain A Bit ... I Am New To Mongo DB Thank You